# Aligning in the aligned equations in widetext

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I have expressions that I'd like to have aligned so that the first letters are aligned, but that the whole thing is still in center. I have this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prc,floats,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,centering,hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom 
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text

\begin{widetext}
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
U &= -\pi/2 \\
V &=\pi/2
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u &\to -\infty \\
v &\to \infty
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
r &\to \infty \\
t &\ \textrm{konačan}
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\begin{aligned}
&\textrm{prostorna} \\
&\infty,\ i_0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
U &= \pm\pi/2 \\
V &=\pm\pi/2
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u &\to \pm\infty \\
v &\to \pm\infty
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
r &\ \textrm{konačan} \\
t &\to \pm\infty
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\begin{aligned}
&\textrm{prošla i buduća} \\
&\textrm{vremenska}\ \infty,\ i_\pm
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{widetext}



Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom text


\end{document}
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

I'd like that the U and V are aligned in every row. Is it possible without renaming and redefining commands? 
Flushleft isn't helping, and centering doesn't do anything :

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Just use `align` rather than two `equation`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prc,floats,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,centering,hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom 
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text

\begin{widetext}
\begin{align}
&\left.
\begin{aligned}
U &= -\pi/2 \\
V &=\pi/2
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u &\to -\infty \\
v &\to \infty
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
r &\to \infty \\
t &\ \textrm{konačan}
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\begin{aligned}
&\textrm{prostorna} \\
&\infty,\ i_0
\end{aligned}
\\
&\left.
\begin{aligned}
U &= \pm\pi/2 \\
V &=\pm\pi/2
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u &\to \pm\infty \\
v &\to \pm\infty
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
r &\ \textrm{konačan} \\
t &\to \pm\infty
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\begin{aligned}
&\textrm{prošla i buduća} \\
&\textrm{vremenska}\ \infty,\ i_\pm
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{widetext}



Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom text


\end{document}
```

Comment: I totally haven't thought of that XD Thank you :)

Comment: if you want the two equations separated by a bit of space, add it immediately after the `\\` separating the two equations, e.g. `\\[4pt]`.  (don't leave a space before the open bracket.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton is casting her (disapproving) proof reading eyes over my posted output, do as she says:-) that is `\\[4pt]`